# Is it possible to "revive" deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I would like to know if it's possible to bring back to life a post of mine (a question) which I deleted?
If so - would the reputation I gained from it be restored?

Comment: Post deletion is soft, deleted questions and answers can be restored. That said, I don't see any deleted questions on your Programmers account.

Comment: That's true, I was just wondering what would happen if I post something and afterwards I felt it stupid. Will I be able to regret?
BTW - how can you see I don't have any deleted questions? I couldn't find it in my profile.

Comment: That little diamond next to my username gives me a couple of superpowers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post deletion is "soft;" deleted questions and answers can be restored. Users with more than 10K reputation can vote to undelete questions and users with more than 20K reputation can also vote to undelete answers. *Except* when those posts were deleted by a moderator, in which case they can only be undeleted by a moderator.

If you've deleted one of your answers, you can easily restore it. When it comes to questions the situation is a bit trickier. You can't see your deleted questions in your profile (that's an abillity reserved for moderators), you can only see them if you have a direct link to them. Also, you can't delete your own question when it has an upvoted answer and you can't delete your own answer if it has been accepted.

When it comes to reputation, when a post is deleted all reputation changes are as if they never happened. *Except* if the post was deleted more than two months after it was posted *and* it had a score of at least 3. If that's the case, you keep all earned reputation. When a post is undeleted, all associated reputation changes are restored.

Comment: Just clarification, 10ks can vote to delete and undelete *questions* (under certain circumstances). Answer deletion
 is reserved for 20k (also limited circumstances).

Comment: @Kevin Oops! Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Where exactly do I see my deleted answers?

Comment: @Avi - if you view a question where you deleted an answer you'll see that answer. You don't see links to deleted posts in your profile.

Comment: @Avi In the question page (they'd appear with a red background), assuming the question itself isn't deleted.

Comment: Thanks @YannisRizos. So, I understand that when you told me you couldn't see any deleted question it's because you're a moderator, right? I can't see delete questions by others if I understand it right.
And a on/off-topic question - is being a moderator a question of reputation? Or how else you become a moderator?

Comment: @Avi Yes, I can see deleted posts on profiles because I'm a moderator (and here's the [rest of team diamond](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)). Every now and then we have [moderator elections](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/), the [last one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/election/3) was fairly recent. Having a bit of reputation is helpful when you're running in an election, but it's not the more important factor. When I was elected, I was the 7th candidate by rep out of 9 candidates.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info!