# Undelete particular question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

Can some of the moderators revive (undelete) [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/245703/57759) (my own) and it's answers? I was more than sure that it is completely useless and voted to close or delete it. But, other users suggests in comments, that even this kind of questions should bring some value to the community.

Unfortunately, I was too slow and read these comments after question was deleted by moderator. As per [this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5938/57759), I can see that questions and answer deleted by moderators can be revived only by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undeleted. I also cleaned up some of the comments.

Comment: Thanks! I also deleted my own answer to this question, as requested in comments to it.

Comment: @trejder Missed that the first time. Done and edited.

Comment: Thomas, I deleted my own answer _intentionally_! :] I think others wanted my answer to remain **deleted**! :] I don't see comments to it now (gone?), but someone clearly stated, that I expressed my opinion in comment to both my question and to the other answer, so my own answer isn't required any more. Now, since you've undeleted my answer, but without comments, I got completely lost! :]